# ArrayLists better practice

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have written 2 methods in Java. Second method looks cleaner to me because I come from python background, but I think it will be slower than first because indexOf() also does the iteration? Is there a way to use for in loop correctly in situation like this? Also, if there is better way to do it (without Streams), how can it be done?

```
private ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;
```

First method:

```
private int findObject(String objectName) {
    for(int i=0; i<this.myObjects.size(); i++) {
        MyObject myObject = this.myObjects.get(i);
        if(myObject.getName().equals(objectName)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Second method:

```
private int findObject(String objectName) {
    for(MyObject myObject: this.myObjects) {
        if(myObject.getName().equals(objectName)) return this.myObjects.indexOf(myObject);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The difference between the two is neglible, I'd argue that the second method is more "expensive" because you are iterating over the array first and then looking up an item if a certain condition is met. Use whichever `for loop` suits your needs. If you need the index, then use the regular for loop (your first method).

Comment: Yes, by slower I meant more "expensive". Is there a way to do something like `for i, myObject in enumerate(myObjects)` would be in python, but with forIn loop instead of standard for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it will be slower than first because indexOf() also does the iteration?

You are correct.

> Is there a way to use `for each` loop correctly in situation like this?

You can use a `for each` AND an index variable.

```
private int findObject(String objectName) {
    int i = 0;
    for (MyObject myObject: this.myObjects) {
        if (myObject.getName().equals(objectName)) return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This would be a good solution if `myObjects.get(i)` is an expensive operation (e.g. on a `LinkedList` where `get(n)` is `O(N)`) or if it is not implementable (e.g. if you were iterating a `Stream`).

You could also use a `ListIterator` *provided* that `myObjects` has a method that returns a `ListIterator`; see @Andy Turner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323656/139985) for an example.  (It won't work for a typical `Set` or `Map` class.)

Answer (score 1):

The first version is perfect **if you know you're working with an ArrayList** (or some other array-based List, e.g. Vector).

If `myObject` happens to be a `LinkedList` or similar, your performance will degrade with longer lists, as then `get(i)` no longer executes in constant time.

Your second approach will handle `LinkedList`s as well as `ArrayList`s, but it iterates twice over your list, once in your `for` loop, and once in the `indexOf()` call.

I'd recommend a third version: use the for loop from the second approach, and add an integer counting variable, incrementing inside the loop. This way, you get the best of both: iterating without performance degradation, and cheap position-counting.

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing this (that avoids you having to maintain a separate index variable; and works for non-`RandomAccess` lists too) would be to use a `ListIterator`:

```
for (ListIterator<MyObject> it = myObjects.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  MyObject myObject = it.next();
  if(myObject.getName().equals(objectName)) return it.prevIndex();
}
return -1;
```